# Is there a way to separate strings in HTML?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the address of some companies from WSJ.com. However, I couldn't figure out a reliable way to separate the city and the state/province from the HTML page.

here's my code and output

```
    code = "TURN"
    url = "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/{}".format(code)
    headers = {'User-Agent':str(ua.random)}
    page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    page.encoding = page.apparent_encoding
    pageText = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageText, 'html.parser')
    
    address = soup.find('div', {"class" : "WSJTheme--contact--bDuH_KYx"}).contents[0]
    print(address.contents[2]) 

Output: <span class="">Montclair New Jersey 07042</span>
```

I want to get a result like [Montclair, New Jersey]. However, I cant simply separate the string by space since there are inputs like "San Diego California 92130" or "Beijing Beijing 100022" which requires different rules to separate them.

They are separated strings in the original HTML code, I'm not sure if this helps.

```
<span class="">
  "Montclair" 
  "New Jersey" 
  "07042"
</span>
```

Comment: if original HTML keeps it in separated lines using `\n` then it should gives you text also with `\n` and you should split it on `\n` but if HTML doesn't have any special chars between lines then there is no method to split it. It would need some dictionary/list with all names to check which is correct `Montclair` or `Montclair New`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest grabbing the zip code and then using a library like:  https://pypi.org/project/zipcodes/

Answer (score 0):

If html really looks like you portrayed it, you can simply split at quotes.

```
a = address.contents[2].text
b = a.split('"', 4)
city = b[1]
state = b[3]
print(f"{city}, {state}")

output: Montclair, New Jersey
```